How to enable sticky sessions for a streamlit application deployed on cloud foundry?
I have a streamlit application deployed on enterprise cloud foundry with single instance currently. As part of scaling horizontally, I am seeing an issue with streamlit file_uploader widget and resolution to this issue mentioned here was to enable session affinity/sticky session.
After referring to this page, I understand I need to set JSESSIONID cookie as part of response which I did and I still see PUT request from file_uploader widget going to a different instance ID. Apart from setting my JSESSIONID cookie in my streamlit app, is there any other step I need to take care of?
Below is the code snippet I used to set the JSESSIONID in streamlit app.
from streamlit_cookies_controller import CookieController
import time
import uuid

def post_auth():
    controller = CookieController()
    cookies = controller.getAll()
    time.sleep(5)
    if (cookies is None) or ('JSESSIONID' not in cookies):
        value = str(uuid.uuid4())  
        controller.set('JSESSIONID', value, secure=True)
    # rest of my app code ...

